# Remove Host from the url and make query string as host

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying reverse proxy with redirect. I am trying to remove the host from the url and construct the url from the query string. Like

`http://www.examplehost.com/newexample.com:8080/` 
-> 
`http://www.newexample.com:8080/`

Query string sent to the url is dynamic.

I have done something like this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.examplehost.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1 [NC,QSA]`

But it is generating `http://www./newexample.com:8080/` which is throwing error.

How do I convert the query string to new URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

[`http\S*\/(.*\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/ToQctm/2)

and replace with `http://www.$1`. The regular expression will capture the last part of the URL (between the last two slashes). This will match and replace URLs of indefinite length and domain, for example:

```
http://www.examplehost.com/newexample.com:8080/
https://somedomain.edu/moretext/finaltext.com:80/
```

will become:

```
http://www.newexample.com:8080/
http://www.finaltext.com:80/
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Regex:

```
^http:\/\/www\.examplehost\.com\/(.*)$
```

and replace with:

```
http://www.$1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ToQctm/1/)

```
RewriteRule ^http:\/\/www\.examplehost\.com\/(.*)$ http://www.$1 [NC,QSA]
```